# Azure Active Directory Authentication Library - not working in Google Pixel (Android Nougat 7.1.1)

Tags: android, android-studio, adal, android-version, android-7.1-nougat

I try to run my Android app using the ADAL in the Android Google Pixel which runs on Android version 7.1.1.In the android Nougat 7.1.1, it gives the following error. I Don't know whether the ADAL supports 7.1.1.

The error in the android nougat 7.1.1 is as follows

> com.microsoft.aad.adal.authenticationException:code:-11 primary error: 5 certificate: issued to:CN=sercure.aadcdn.microsoftonline-p.com,O=Microsoft corporation, L=redmond, ST=Washington, C=US;
>   Issued by: CN=Symantec Trust Network, O=Symantec Corporation, C=US;
>   on URL:https://secure.aadcdn.microsoftonline-p.com/ests/2.1.5364.5/content/cnbundles/jquery.1.11.min.js correlationId:6dc07a37-b7e8-4ea9-9e8e-92d62ed2c0b1

Comment: According to the newest log of adal4android changelog "Upgrad the SDK to Marshmallow and Target SDK version to 23", it seems to not be generally available supported on android 7.0(api 24) & 7.1(api 25).  Very greet if you can post an issue at https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-android/issues to report this issue and your testing log or fiddler log for helping resolving it faster.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone still encounters the similar issue: I got it on my HTC device running Android 5.0.x and after updated Android System WebView via Play Store, the problem seems to be fixed. Please refer to:

https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-android/wiki/SSL-Certificate-Validation-Issue